# Mobile URL Redirect and Desktop URL Redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mobile

I need help please? I want to make my website that has a desktop and a mobile version. The **CSS** coding of styling to the correct widths of HTML elements are easy but a **URL** is harder. 
I want to know is that how to make a **URL** that leads to a home page on desktop but on mobile the URL is different but it goes to the same home page as the desktop version but in the mobile version. 
Do you know if there is any code that can do that with out getting any errors on previewing it privately. I don't mind if your answers are using `PHP` or `JavaScript` etc.

This is a code that i tried to use. I wasn't sure if it worked or not. Can't say it possibly did.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on("load resize", function() {
        if($(window).width() <= 950) {
            var mobile = window.location = "/mindex.php";
            console.log("The location is " + mobile);
        } else if($(window).width() > 950) {
            var desktop = window.location = "/index.php";
            console.log("The location is " + desktop);
        } else {
            var defaultPlace = "";
            console.log("Defualt location: " + defaultPlace);
        }
    });
});
```

Can you please help me? Remember, I would like some help on making a mobile redirect URL and a desktop URL but that will both lead to the same page but in different versions please.

Comment: Why not do this with PHP? Or use CSS boilerplates like Bootstrap? which focuses on mobile first development.

Comment: See... Instead of getting screen size on every page load you can set a session name on first then checking the session and redirect it...

Comment: Instead of using session (It is the worst idea) use header to get the OS of the User and other details like device name, device type and redirect if a mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **user-agent header** sent by the browser to check whether the user is mobile user or desktop user and redirect according to the returned value. You can check user-agent header using this -

```
var usrAgent = navigator.userAgent;
```

Now you know the user agent, check the returned user-agent is mobile or not and redirect accordingly -

```
function detectMobile() 
{
    if(usrAgent.match(/Mobile/i))
    {
        return "Mobile";
    }
}

var isMobile = detectMobile();

if(isMobile)
{
    window.location = "MOBILE_URL";
}
else
{
    window.location = "DESKTOP_URL";
}
```

**Alternatively,**

You can use html **link** tag to redirect to any webpage according to user device width using this -

```
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px*)" href="MOBILE_URL_TO_REDIRECT">
```

*Change this width according to your requirement. 640px is the ideal max width for mobile devices.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: To be honest with you, your code works and I see how but i tried it and it keep reloading the page every 1 second flat and doesn't display anything at all. it acts like if it was a infinite loop that never stops. the console log message displays but it meant to show if it is working. So your code works but it loads the page repetivley like a infinite loop. So do you have any ideas to solve this problem? :D

Comment: but by the way as well as that problem it helps a lot thanks :D